# RSpec tests fails without factory_girl reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was having trouble getting one of my spec tests to pass until I forced a reload on the user object after an activation. I'm fairly new to BDD and rails, am I completely misusing factory girl in this instance? Should I have mocked something instead?

For reference I am using the sorcery gem for user activation.

```
describe "GET activate" do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "activates a new user" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_user)
      expect {
        get :activate, id: user.activation_token
        user.reload
      }.to change{user.activation_state}.from("pending").to("active")
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's confusing here is how you are triggering activate vs. how you are trying to verify that it worked.

You're activating via the controller `get :activate`, but then validating via the model `user.activation_state`.  `reload` is necessary in this case, because you have to reload the attributes from the database in order to see that `activation_state` has been changed from pending to active.  `get :activate` has no affect on your `user` instance.

To make it more clear you could:

1. Check for an activation result on the page that activate responds with or check a controller instance variable (there's probably an @user)
2. Perform the activation from the model instead.  I assume this could be a unit test that instead calls some `user.activate(activation_token)` method.  Then, checking the `user` instance without reload will work.

Comment: Makes sense. Still trying to understand where everything should go in rails. Thanks for your help.